# On iOS, what is the difference between adding a subview to a UITableViewCell object "cell" vs to "cell.contentView"?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In the following code, if we do  `[cell addSubview: someLabel]` vs `[cell.contentView addSubview: someLabel]`, they seem to work the same.  Is there any difference doing one or the other?  (the custom cell in the real code is adding `UIImageView` and `UILabel`)  (`UIView`, on the other hand, doesn't have `contentView`, so we don't need to add subview to its `contentView`.  `UITableViewCell` is a subclass of `UIView` by the way)

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView 
                       cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    if ([tableView isEqual:self.songsTableView]){

        static NSString *TableViewCellIdentifier = @"MyCells";

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableViewCellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil){
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                    reuseIdentifier:TableViewCellIdentifier];
        }

        // ...  some code to create a UILabel (not shown here)

        [cell addSubview: someLabel];  // vs using [cell.contentView addSubView: ...]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe If I am not wrong, the contentView is a subview of UITableViewCell.

If you look at this page [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1), you can see there are actually 3 subviews in a UITableViewCell

I think by default, the Editing Control is hidden until you enter edit mode for a table in which case, the Editing Control appears (the minus button left of each row) and your contentView gets resized and pushed to the right. This is probably what gives the "proper animation" effect mentioned by the other answer.

To test the difference, try adding a subview such as UILabel with text, to the cell rather than the cell.contentView. When you add it to cell rather than cell.contentView and you enter edit mode for your table, I believe your UILabel will not resize, you will see the edit button ontop/below the minus sign button.

Comment: yes I found the reason is not to interfere with other regions of a cell... but interestingly, even if I use `contentView`, the delete icon can bring in a `Delete` button, and it covers up the content area

Comment: and it shows underneath the Accessory as well, even if contentView is used, but maybe it is due to the contentView showing something beyond the content area, and it is confirmed if I show an image at `x = 0` at the content area, and then change it to `x = -16`, and it will go underneath the delete icon in the Edit region too.

Answer (score 3):

Placing your views in the [`contentView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/contentView) affects proper animation in and out of edit mode. Place all of your subviews in `contentView` when you're not subclassing, which should be all of the time unless you know what you're doing.